# Building kernel 5.10 for blueline

Tags: linux-kernel, android-source, google-pixel

I was wondering if there's a way for me to port kernel 5.10 to my device Google Pixel 3 (blueline) as the official Google support ended with kernel 4.9, but there's features that I need of kernel 5.10 that are not present in the kernel 4.9, so can you tell me how can I build kernel 5.10 for blueline? As far as I know, it is completely possible. By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 for all of this.

I tried using a GKI (Generic Kernel Image) of the kernel 5.10 with an Android 13 ROM but it didn't boot (i used both the boot.img and the uncompressed kernel image, none of them boots). I used fastboot to flash them:

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
```

```
fastboot boot boot.img
```

Comment: You posted to a wrong site. But anyway, look at the LineageOS: https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/blueline/, maybe it gives you any hints.

Comment: I didn't see something about kernel on the LineageOS Wiki, and btw, where should I post this question?

Comment: It's v4.19 for the latest available for that device.

Comment: I know, but I know that is possible to use Kernel v5.10 on Snapdragon 845 SoC

Answer (score 0):

it is not that straightforward. Please take a look at PostMarketOS
https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/SDM845_Mainlining

and AOSP M:
https://github.com/aospm